# Partial derivative of a function of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose $z=f(x+y)$. Taking partial derivatives w.r.t. $x$ on either side:
$\partial z/\partial x = \partial f(x+y)/\partial x$. Let us denote $x+y$ by $u$. So $\partial z/\partial x = \partial f(u(x,y))/\partial x$. How do I evaluate the R.H.S. The chain rule I know is for finding total derivatives and not partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ (or $f$) depends on a single variable $u$, which in turn depends on two variables $x$ and $y$, then $z$ is a function of those two "ultimately" independent variables $x$ and $y$, and by (a multivariate version of) the Chain Rule:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}u}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}u}\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}.$$

Although this is not in your question, but let me point out that there are many versions of multivariate functions, because we can combine functions of different numbers of variables in all kinds of different ways. For example, if $z$ depends on two variables $u$ and $v$, both of which in turn depend on a single variable $x$, then $z$ is a function of that one "ultimately" independent variable $x$ only, and the appropriate version of the Chain Rule is:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}.$$

The graphs below can you help understand multivariate chain rules for these two examples, as well as assist in setting it up correctly for any other composition of functions:

[image]

Arrows indicate how functions depend on variables. And to set up the correct chain rule, you find all trajectories from the top-level function to the same bottom-level variable and add together "chain rules" along those paths.

Comment: Single branch would indicate the use of ordinary derivatives and multiple branches on the same level would suggest the use of partial derivatives, right?

Comment: @HritRoy: Yes, exactly.

Comment: I see. And since you brought it up I must ask you this : the "total derivative" can have the form ∂F/∂t or dF/dt, depending upon the situation. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, the total derivative is usually written in the form $\mathrm{d}F/\mathrm{d}x$ -- precisely to distinguish it from the partial derivative with respect to the same variable.

Comment: But then in your first example, what would be the total derivative of z w.r.t. x if not ∂z/∂x? How would dz/dx (the total derivative as you said) be any different from ∂z/∂x?

Comment: @HritRoy: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative. Talking about the total derivative requires more context. Roughly speaking, the concept of a total derivative only makes sense when all intermediate variables depend on the "ultimate" independent variable -- the only one, the single independent variable. If $x$ and $y$ are truly independent of each other, then you can't even ask about the total derivative of $z$ with respect to $x$, as it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Could you still answer the question? In your first example, what is the total derivative of z w.r.t. x?

Comment: Then what if I have a function that looks like this : F(x,y,z(x,y))? There is no one independent variable. dF/dx = ∂F/∂x + (∂F/∂z)(∂z/∂x), right? I certainly can't write ∂F/∂x on the left hand side as well! So what is the thing on the L.H.S.?

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula is
$$\frac{\partial f\bigl(u(x,y)\bigr)}{\partial x}=\frac{\mathrm d\bigl(f\bigl(u(x,y)\bigr)\bigr)}{\mathrm d u}\cdot\frac{\partial \bigl(u(x,y)\bigr)}{\partial x}=\frac{\mathrm d\bigl(f\bigl(u(x,y)\bigr)\bigr)}{\mathrm d u}\cdot 1$$

Comment: That kind of looks like the chain rule. But isn't it used to find total derivatives? Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: The chain rule is also valid for partial derivatives. Here you compose a two-variable function by a single variable function (in that order).

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Thank you. However the second part isn't clear to me. What composition are you talking about? Pardon my ignorance.